# How to fix the garbled code on the bar of Vim？

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vim

As the following picture shows, the information displaying bar in the below has garbled code, I have tried so many ways but it's still not resolved, because many related webs are about garbled code of content rather than information bar of Vim.

Except the garbled code, everything else is fine.

[image]

Maybe related information:

- My environment is wsl2 & Ubuntu 22.04.
- Vim is Vi IMproved 8.2.
- The terminal's font is Meslo LG M for powerline.
- I have installed the following plugins:

  [image]

Comment: Looks like this is related to Windows terminal being unable to render emoji. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940181/cannot-display-emojis-in-windows-powershell-or-wsl-linux-terminal-using-python

Comment: @popey While you (correctly) say "Windows terminal" (generic, lower-case "terminal"), this can cause some confusion, since the solution is to use Windows Terminal (uppercase, proper-noun) which does support emoji.  Just wanted to make it clear(er) for the OP. ;-)